# Dahon Vitesse frame latch

Tags: frames, repair

I am repairing a Dahon Vitesse. The frame latch was incomplete. I have the new frame latch parts but cannot work out where they go, particularly the washers and small springs. Does anyone have a diagram or instructions please?

Comment: By frame latch, do you mean the one that is in the main frame beam, and holds the bike in the open position ?

Comment: Yes, there is just the one on this model. The latch where the frame folds. I can't see where the washers and grub screws go, although the first answer helps with the grub screws. (I thought they were small springs at first!)

Comment: Can you post some photos?  use edit link above to put photos in-line with your question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a dahon brand bike, but folder latches are all reasonably similar because they do exactly the same purpose.

Latch in closed position, with safety removed.  Front of bike is to the right.
[image]

Latch half-opened.  Notice the lever is connected to the latch by a cam mechanism, so as the lever moves the latch moves.  You cannot have the latch closed and the lever open.
[image]

Latch is now fully open, and the frame is free to fold.
[image]

Finally - here's a shot from the front showing the two grub screws used to adjust the seating position of the latch.  Too far in and the closed joint has play, too far out and the latch is hard to close fully.
[image]

Finally - the safety.  This bike doesn't have one because it fell off unnoticed and was lost.  So we use a velcro strap around the frame and it works fine.

The safety was a black plastic block which was screwed to frame just forward of the hinge (you can see the threadded boss in the photos.)  The safety block dropped into that slot you can see in the lever, and was held there by gravity only.  Not confidence inspiring.